# Refresh app when it's connected to the internet

Tags: javascript, react-native

At the moment I have an app with a "there's no internet conection" screen on it. This screen has a "Refresh" button that navigates the user to the previous screen, but it doesn't load anything, even when the internet connection is re-established.

```
onPressBack = () => {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  navigation.goBack();
}
```

How can I refresh the app to force a `componentDidMount()` function to start over again to fetch all the stuff from the internet when the connection has been re-established?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NetInfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) to watch the internet connectivity. In the ComponentDidMount, you can addEventListener which takes an callback. Whenever the connection changes, the callback will be triggered. If the internet is connected, you can load your content/screen.

```
NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  if(state.isConnected) {
    // Load your content here
  }
})
```